MUI DataGridPro with custom component for HeaderFilter is rerendering after first time a letter is entered in the inputBox
I'm trying to set a headerFilter for one column (for instance I´m using "Id") where the rendered component is a AutoComplete where the input is a TextField. For the user, it could be possible to select from a dropdown or find for the option name and then select it (image attached). The problem is that while typing the option name for the first time, it rerenders the component. It only occurs once, after the first load, but then it works start with the expected behaviour, that is filtering while typing.
import React from 'react';
import { TextField, Autocomplete, Checkbox } from "@mui/material";
import CheckBoxIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CheckBox';
import CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CheckBoxOutlineBlank';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import { DataGridPro } from '@mui/x-data-grid-pro';

function CustomFilter() {

    const icon = <CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon fontSize="small" />;
    const checkedIcon = <CheckBoxIcon fontSize="small" />;

    return (
        <FormControl variant="standard" sx={{ m: 1, width: '100%', margin: 0 }} fullWidth>
            <Autocomplete
                limitTags={0}
                getLimitTagsText={(more) => `Selected: ${more}`}
                multiple
                disableCloseOnSelect
                id='autoCompleteComponent'
                name='autoCompleteComponent'
                key="autoCompleteComponent"
                options={[100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900]}
                size="medium"
                fullWidth
                sx={{ width: '100%' }}
                renderTags={(value) => value.map(() => null)}
                renderOption={(props, option, { selected }) => {
                    const { key: propsKey, ...propsWithoutKey } = props
                    return <li key={propsKey} {...propsWithoutKey}>
                        <Checkbox
                            icon={icon}
                            checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
                            style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
                            checked={selected}
                        />
                        {option}
                    </li>
                }}
                renderInput={(params) => {
                    const { InputLabelProps, ...newParams } = params;
                    return (
                        <TextField
                            {...newParams}
                            key="testField"
                            variant="outlined"
                            size="small"
                            fullWidth
                            sx={{ width: '100%', padding: '10px 0' }}
                            value={[100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900]}
                        />)
                }}
            />
        </FormControl>)
}

export function AutoCompleteTest() {

    const initialState = {
        filter: {
            filterModel: {
                items: [
                    {
                        id: 'id',
                        field: 'ID',
                        operator: 'isAnyOf',
                        value: [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900]
                    }
                ],
            }
        }
    }

    return (
        <DataGridPro
            unstable_headerFilters
            columns={[
                {
                    field: 'id', headerName: 'ID', flex: 1, renderHeaderFilter: (params) => (
                        <CustomFilter {...params} />
                    )
                },
                { field: 'firstName', headerName: 'First name', width: 150 },
                { field: 'lastName', headerName: 'Last name', width: 150 },
                { field: 'age', headerName: 'Age', type: 'number', width: 110 },
                { field: 'fullName', headerName: 'Full name', description: 'This column has a value getter and is not sortable.', sortable: false, width: 160 },
            ]}
            rows={[{ id: 100, lastName: 'Snow', firstName: 'Jon', age: 35 }, { id: 200, lastName: 'Lannister', firstName: 'Cersei', age: 42 }, { id: 300, lastName: 'Lannister', firstName: 'Jaime', age: 45 }, { id: 400, lastName: 'Stark', firstName: 'Arya', age: 16 }, { id: 500, lastName: 'Targaryen', firstName: 'Daenerys', age: null }, { id: 600, lastName: 'Melisandre', firstName: null, age: 150 }, { id: 700, lastName: 'Clifford', firstName: 'Ferrara', age: 44 }, { id: 800, lastName: 'Frances', firstName: 'Rossini', age: 36 }, { id: 900, lastName: 'Roxie', firstName: 'Harvey', age: 65 }]}
            rowId="id"
            in
        />
    )
}

rerender when start typing
